# How do I choose the correct airfoil for my fast cargo UAV project?

Tags: airfoil

I am not able to decide which airfoil to choose for my UAV project as I am confused. I need to lift a maximum of 100kg of extra payload excluding the aircraft's fuel and empty weight. Cruise velocity has a range of 200 to 250kph. Also I would like to know if there is any software or application to decide the airfoil for me?

Answer (score 3):

Aircraft design is iterative. It's never as easy as having a program choose an airfoil for you. For example, the size and shape of your wing is going to factor into your empty weight, which in turn feeds back into what kind of performance your wing needs to have, affecting your choice of airfoil.

Basically, what you need to do is generate a configuration, essentially the layout of your aircraft. Think about how big your fuselage needs to be, where propulsion devices will be located, things like that. Maybe look for inspiration in existing UAVs that have capabilities similar to what your project calls for. Once you have that, you can dig into designing the individual systems.

You can take some guesses at the wing's shape, size, and airfoil. Then you check the performance with computational tools. If it works (it won't the first time), great. If not, try again and improve your design using the information you learned. UIUC maintains a large airfoil database that can give you some ideas of where to start: https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_database.html. It sounds like this is an educational project, so you can focus on things like the thickness and camber (degree of curvature) of the airfoil as your iterate.

For example, a thick, highly cambered airfoil would have great takeoff and landing performance, but would stall easily and produce lots of drag in cruise. If I'm finding my aircraft produces high form drag in cruise, I may want to make it thinner to reduce drag. However, be careful not to make the wing so thin that it's too weak to stay attached to the plane (if structural design is important in your project)

Some programs of interest to you might be XFLR5 (http://www.xflr5.com/xflr5.htm) and XFOIL (https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/). XFLR5 is popular for hobby aircraft builders and would probably be an appropriate tool for your project, allowing you to analyze an entire 3D aircraft design. XFOIL is for individual 2D airfoil design.

I'll also refer you to Dan Raymer's book, *Simplified Aircraft Design for Homebuilders*. If you need to build a plane and you don't have an aerospace engineering degree, this is likely the best resource.